# Problems with ubuntu on mac

Tags: installation, mac, macosx

I just finished downloading Ubuntu on my mac and I tried to open it but it says it can't be opened because "it has no mountable file systems". I have no idea what this means, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

OSx is unable to verify the image and throws an error stating that the .iso file does not contain a recognizable filesystem. This [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870261#9) should help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you downloaded the ISO.  What are you trying to get out of it?  If your goal is to install Ubuntu, you'd need to burn the ISO to a disc or put it on a flash drive to boot from it.  There's no 'installation package' for Ubuntu on mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try or install Ubuntu on your mac, first you have to burn the iso to a CD, reboot and keep pressed the `C` key when it starts before it appears the apple logo and will boot from the CD with the Ubuntu iso.